# Terraform interpolation in vpc_security_groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to create 2 ec2-intances by defining it as count and in which one acts as master and another as a worker node. I want to add two different different security groups for each. How can i attach a master security  group to one instance and worker security group to another by using  the parameter "vpc_security_group_ids".
I am not sure how i can apply interpolation in this scenario? Any suggestions!

Ec2-Instance :

```
resource "aws_instance" "tableau_server" {
   count             = 2
   availability_zone = "${lookup(var.availability_zones, count.index)}"
   ami               = "${var.ami_id}"
   instance_type     = "${var.instance_type}"
   key_name          = "${var.key_name}"
   subnet_id         = "${var.subnet_id}"
   associate_public_ip_address = true
   vpc_security_group_ids = [
       "${aws_security_group.tableau_server_sg_master.id}",
       "${aws_security_group.tableau_server_sg_worker.id}",
    ]

  root_block_device {
    volume_type           = "gp2"
    volume_size           = "${var.volume_size}"
    delete_on_termination = true
  }

  tags {
    Name        = "tableau-server_${count.index}_${var.env}"
    Terraform   = "true"
    Environment = "${var.env}"
  }
}
```

Comment: so what's wrong to write two aws_instance resources, one for master and the other for worker?

Comment: we want to increase the count of instances in production environment. For dev env is fine to write.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick fix, you can try to do it like this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "tableau_server" {
  [...]
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${count.index < 1 ?
                              aws_security_group.tableau_server_sg_master.id :
                              aws_security_group.tableau_server_sg_worker.id}"]
  [...]

  tags {
    Name = "tableau-server_${count.index < 1 ? "master" : format("_worker_%d_", count.index)}_${var.env}"
    [...]
  }
}
```

This works, if you have only one master and multiple workers. For more than one worker you need to change the conditional and make it a bit more dynamic (e.g. use variables for the count of master and workers)

If you want to know more about "Conditionals" (The if/else of terraform ^^):
https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#conditionals